# UnstatisfiedLinkError while trying to use jepp in windows

Tags: java, python, windows

I am new to java.I have written some python scripts and need to run them from java as desired by my mentor(these scripts are to be deployed on a server).So I have installed Jepp on my windows xp.However when I run

```
C:\Program Files\Jepp>java -classpath jep.jar jep.Run console.py
```

I get

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\WINDOWS\system32\jep.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1803)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1728)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
at jep.Jep.<clinit>(Jep.java:136)
at jep.Run.run(Run.java:54)
at jep.Run.main(Run.java:153)
```

I have included the system32 folder containing jep.dll and the Program Files\jepp folder in PATH env. variable but still it is showing the same error.Are there any other directories that need to be included in the PATH variable?

Also in the readme file in jepp dir. for installation,it is given:

> Also, you'll likely need to add -Djava.library.path='path to
>   Release folder' for testing. Or copy and register the DLL in the
>   System directory.

The jep.dll is already present in system32 directory.What other DLL might have been referred to here.

Ive also tried

```
C:\Program Files\Jepp>java -classpath jep.jar jep.Run console.py -Djava.library.path='C:\Program Files\Jepp'
```

but it still gives the same UnsatisfiedLinkError :(
Am I wrong in adding the -Djava.library.path command as in above or is it supposed to be added somewhere else?

I am so confused and getting all kinds of doubts as i've been struggling with this for the past 2 days :( .Even the online documentation is not so detailed and helpful.I would really appreciate any suggestions regarding this....
thanks in advance!

Comment: try to put the java.library.path at the first option:
C:\Program Files\Jepp>java -Djava.library.path='C:\Program Files\Jepp' -classpath jep.jar jep.Run console.py

Comment: thanks for the reply,
when I try that I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files\Jepp\'.The program then ends after saying Could not find the main class: Files\Jepp\'.

Comment: I tried some things, including installing jep and launching it... but it results on the same errors as you.
I did'nt find any solutions...sorry